# Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' to 'NSArray in Google Place Api

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

i integrated Google Place Api to fetch user location, i have to fetch "area","state" and "City" while i try to get value my App gets crash. Please post ur answer

here my sample code

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, idleAtCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        let centerLocation = CLLocation(latitude: position.target.latitude, longitude: position.target.longitude)
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(centerLocation, completionHandler:
            {(placemarks, error) in
            if (error == nil && placemarks!.count>0)
            {

                let placemark = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarksArray[0] as! CLPlacemark)

                let latitude = String(format: "%.8f",position.target.latitude)
                let longitude = String(format: "%.8f",position.target.longitude)


                if let addrList = placemark.addressDictionary
                {

                    print("address==\(address)")
                    let addStr  = address?["FormattedAddressLines"] as! [String]

                    let addStr1  = address?["City"] as! [String]
                    let addStr2  = address?["State"] as! [String]
                    let addStr3  = address?["SubLocality"] as! [String]

                    NSLog("%@\n%@\n%@", addStr1,addStr2,addStr3)
                    self.addressLabel.text = addStr.joinWithSeparator(",")



                }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

my output :

```
address=={
City = "New Delhi";
Country = India;
CountryCode = IN;
FormattedAddressLines =     (
    "Mayur Vihar",
    "New Delhi",
    "Delhi 110092",
    India
);
Name = 110092;
State = Delhi;
SubAdministrativeArea = Delhi;
SubLocality = "Mayur Vihar";
ZIP = 110092;
```

}

and my Crash Report :

```
 Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x1064cb860) to 'NSArray' (0x1064cb900).
```

Comment: Which line does the app crash on?  The messGe is clear ; you are casting a string to an array, so someting that you think is an array is actually a string - certainly, city. State and sublocality are not arrays yet you are force down casting them as arrays

Comment: app gets crash at addStr1,addStr2,addStr3

Comment: Yes because they are strings, not string arrays which you are force downcasting them to

Comment: so what will be the solution how to fetch them ?

Comment: Remove the [] and just as `as! String`

Comment: ok will try and come back to u :)

Comment: Thanks Bro its worked

Answer (score 0):

City and State has String value and FormattedAddressLines has Arry.

Use like this

```
let addStr1  = address["City"] as! String
let addStr2  = address["State"] as! String
let FormattedAddressLines = address["FormattedAddressLines"] as![String]
```

Comment: you could provide a bit of context on why your answer work :-)